# Is there a way to find max and min number using only while and if in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Program Is Running\n");
    int number, counter, max, min;
    counter = 0;
    max, min = number;
    while (counter < 10) {
        scanf("%d", &number);
        if (number >= max) {
            max = number;
        }
        if (number <= min) {
            min = number;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    printf("Max = %d\n", max);
    printf("Min = %d\n", min);
    return 0;
}
```

So the problem is, the printed max value always shows `16` if I dont input a number greater than `16` like `15`, `14`, `13`, and so on. Any solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: `int number,..; max, min = number;` What do you think the value of `number` is at that point? Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and step thru the code line by line.

Comment: Please do a search on "comma operator". It doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Hint : First input number will always be the min and the max

Comment: The most important thing : **always** indent correctly your code. The `while` scope isn't indented

Comment: Important: Compile with `-Wall -Wextra`. I got this from your code: `warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect`

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work because you do initialize `min` and `max` from `number` before the loop, an uninitialized variable. A good solution is to check in the loop if you just read the first number to set `min` and `max`.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number, counter, max, min;

    printf("Program Is Running\n");
    counter = 0;
    while (counter < 10 && scanf("%d", &number) == 1) {
        if (count == 0) {
            max = min = number;
        } else
        if (number > max) {
            max = number;
        } else
        if (number < min) {
            min = number;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    if (counter > 0) {
        printf("Max = %d\n", max);
        printf("Min = %d\n", min);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

An alternative solution to avoid testing `count` at each iteration is to initialize `min` and `max` to `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` respectively:

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number, counter, max, min;

    printf("Program Is Running\n");
    counter = 0;
    min = INT_MAX;
    max = INT_MIN;
    while (counter < 10 && scanf("%d", &number) == 1) {
        if (number > max) {
            max = number;
        } else
        if (number < min) {
            min = number;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    if (counter > 0) {
        printf("Max = %d\n", max);
        printf("Min = %d\n", min);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your "modified version" has no difference from the code in the question.

Comment: @MikeCAT: oops! I posted the answer too quickly. Fixed now.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &number) == 1` what does that mean?

Comment: @user14360970 It means that one number was successfully read.

Comment: @user14360970: `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions. If `scanf()` does not return `1` it means either invalid input was provided that is not a number or end of file has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

Read once outside the loop

```
if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

assign that initial, one-time value to both `min` and `max`

```
min = max = number;
```

then loop as you have, remember to decerease `count`

```
    while (counter < 9) {
        if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        if (number > max) max = number; // no need to assign
        if (number < min) min = number; // if already equal
        counter++;
    }
```